# Pact - matching an array of integers

Tags: java, arrays, testing, pact

I'm using Pact and creating consumer tests. My response body for a specific request looks like:

```
PactDslJsonBody responseBody = new PactDslJsonBody()
                .stringType("response","success")
                .array("accounts")
                    .integerType()
                .closeArray()
                .asBody();
```

I want to modify this so it returns an array of random integers (not objects) with 10 or less elements (now it only returns one and provider expects to match only one). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Random numbers are not recommended, as it means that when you publish a pact, it will change every time you publish, and you won't get the benefits of "pre-verification" as described in the Pact Broker wiki here: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker/wiki/Provider-verification-results#querying

Comment: You're right, what I want is my pact to match "any integer" inside the array. This is a paginated query so given some parameters I want to make sure that it will return certain structure with 0 to page-size results.